# How to filter data by orderId

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongodb-query, populate

It is my response
{
success: true,
data: { items: [ [Object] ] },
pagination: { totalCount: 1, pageCount: 1, currentPage: 1, perPage: 40 },
status: 200
}
console.log(response);
if ((!validate || (validate(item) && (!!item.distributor_br_id && $distributorArr.length > 0 && $distributorArr.includes(item.distributor_br_id))))) {
await this.createOrUpdate(modelDoc, item, uniqueFieldName);
}
This is my if condition, I will have to onw more condition in this check exist of companyID which is the proopertt of data

Comment: Can you please provide the full function code (well formatted)?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.